# Show Snackbar in MainActivity (root @Composable) from any child composable (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to show a snackbar in the MainActivity (root composable) from any child `@Composable`.

My first thought was to provide the `SnackbarHostState` using `CompositionLocalProvider` but that doesn't seem to work (or I'm doing it incorrectly).

```kotlin
    val mainSnackBarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val SnackBarHostStateProvider = compositionLocalOf<SnackbarHostState> { mainSnackBarHostState }

    CompositionLocalProvider(SnackBarHostStateProvider provides mainSnackBarHostState) {
        MainScreenNavigationConfigurations(navController)
    }
```

My child `@Composable` can't seem to find/access `SnackBarHostStateProvider`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess you "must" define things like snack bar in the composable that covers the entire screen(i.e your root layout) and define a livedata to interact with the snack bar in a viewmodel and pass that view model down the composable tree with ```CompositonLocalProvider``` and interact from anywhere in the code at anytime

Answer (score 1):

The best way, I'd say, is to store the state of the snackbar (visible/invisible) in your viewmodel, and let the snackbar read from there. Whenever and wherever from you want to toggle the state, just change the value in the viewmodel, and that should do it

If you are unfamiliar with viewmodel, it is the recommended and standard way to build apps, and remember, in Compose, the recommended way is to store state in the viewmodel not as regular variables, but as stateholders.

For instance, in your use case, you can store the visibility status of your snackbar as mutableStateOf(false), for am initial visibility value of false.

This assumes that you have access to your viewmodel from all over your app, which usually developers do, wherever they need to update state, so, best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to declare the variable `SnackBarHostStateProvider` as a package-level variable, to be able to access it from the provider and the children.

See also this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69905470/293878