# How to show snackbars from Composables or ViewModels on a multi-module, single activity, Compose only, project

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar

What's the best way to show a Snackbar on a multi-module, single
activity, Compose only project?

This is how the project dependency graph looks like:

[image: dependency graph]

The only activity of the project is inside the `app` module and it [just sets the `NavHost` as content](https://github.com/leinardi/AndroidTemplateProject/blob/4beba33723ec84e606d5302335248552d530e020/app/src/main/kotlin/com/leinardi/template/ui/MainActivity.kt#L99).

Each `feature` module [provides a list of composable screens](https://github.com/leinardi/AndroidTemplateProject/blob/4beba33723ec84e606d5302335248552d530e020/modules/feature-foo/src/main/kotlin/com/leinardi/template/foo/feature/FooFeature.kt#L29) that will be shown on the `NavHost`.

Each screen has [its own `Scaffold`](https://github.com/leinardi/AndroidTemplateProject/blob/4beba33723ec84e606d5302335248552d530e020/modules/feature-foo/src/main/kotlin/com/leinardi/template/foo/ui/FooScreen.kt#L84), so it can easily show Snackbars from the each screen's `ViewModel`.

There is a special `feature` module, `feature-debug`, that shows on a single screen, [a list of composable](https://github.com/leinardi/AndroidTemplateProject/blob/4beba33723ec84e606d5302335248552d530e020/modules/feature-debug/src/main/kotlin/com/leinardi/template/debug/ui/DebugScreen.kt#L182) provided by [each `feature` module](https://github.com/leinardi/AndroidTemplateProject/blob/4beba33723ec84e606d5302335248552d530e020/modules/feature-foo/src/main/kotlin/com/leinardi/template/foo/feature/FooFeature.kt#L33), that are called debug sections. It is used to allow any `feature` module to show automatically some settings inside the debug screen.

Each debug section has its own `ViewModel` so it works exactly like a Screen. But it's missing a Scaffold, since it only takes a portion of the screen:

```
+-------------------------+
| Debug screen            |
|-------------------------+
|                         |
| Feature A debug section |
|                         |
|------------------------ +
|                         |
| Feature B debug section |
|                         |
|------------------------ +
|                         |
| Feature C debug section |
|                         |
|------------------------ +
|                         |
| Feature D debug section |
|                         |
+------------------------ +
```

So I'm not sure how can I show a Snackbar on the Scaffold of the `feature-debug` screen, from a composable that is declared inside another `feature` module that has no visibility of the any class inside `feature-debug`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`CompositionLocal`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/CompositionLocal) can be used to pass data through the composition tree implicitly.

The first thing to do is to declare a variable that must be visible by provider and consumers (in my case, I created it inside the `core-ui` module):

```
val LocalSnackbarHostState = compositionLocalOf<SnackbarHostState> { error("No SnackbarHostState provided") }
```

Then the provider should wrap its children with a `CompositionLocalProvider`:

```
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalSnackbarHostState provides scaffoldState.snackbarHostState
    ) {
        Scaffold(
[...]
```

And finally the children can grab an instance of the `SnackbarHostState` accessing the variable `LocalSnackbarHostState`:

```
val snackbarHostState = LocalSnackbarHostState.current
```

Answer (score 0):

I would only use a single snackbar for your entire app. It needs to be included at the root level of your UI hierarchy and accessible through a global object. This can be done by using a class that inherits from Application and placing a method inside that class to handle displaying the snackbar.

There's an example app showing how this is done. The demo app can be downloaded at:

https://github.com/JohannBlake/Jetmagic

When you run the app, open up the navigation tray and select any navigation item. On the screen that appears, click on the button labeled `Return value from another screen`. This will take you to another screen where you select an item and return to the previous screen. The selected item will be shown in a snackbar. This snackbar is global throughout the app.